# A simple differential equation with non-zero boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How can I solve for $f(\cdot)$ from the following differential equation?
$$\frac{d}{dx}\big(f(x)g(x)\big)=xg'(x)~~\textrm{and}~~f(0)=z.$$
Here, we have $z<0$ and $g(0)=0$. $f$ is assumed to be defined over a unit interval.

If we had $z=0$, the equation can be solved nicely and we can conclude $$f(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}\int^x_0yg'(y)dy.$$ 
But what happens if $z$ is strictly negative? Can we get a closed form solution for $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct. The only possible solution is $f(x)=\frac 1 {g(x)} {\int_0^{x} yg'(y)dy}$ for $x>0$. But now $f(x)\to 0$ as $ x\to 0$ at least when $g$ is a nice function so the given IVP has no solution. [ $|f(x)| \leq \frac {x\int_0^{x} g'(y)dy} {|g(x)|}= x \to 0$ if  $g'$ is positive, for example].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if we take your $f$ as an answer, we have $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)g(x))=zg'(x)+xg'(x)$..

Comment: @Andeanlll I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you. So, for that differential equation, there's no solution in general except for a very specific boundary condition, namely $f(0)=0$?

Comment: That is right. There is a solution only when $z=0$.